# What is the source of the chittim?

Tags: nsibidi-scripts

In the *Akata Witch* series by Nnedi Okorafor, Leopard People (mages, in essence) receive chittim, a form of currency, when they reach some type of realization, acquire new knowledge or experience, and so forth. These tokens appear essentially from thin air and are used as a medium of exchange by Leopard People.

Who or what is the source of the chittim? A masquerade, a natural process, some sort of ancient juju or other magical working? Something else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This may not be the most satisfying of answers, but according to an [interview with Okorafor](https://mechanicaldolphin.com/2011/07/06/nnedi-okorafor-interview-part-4-chittim-and-earning-for-learning/) she herself does not know (or has not decided) where chittim comes from:

> ‘The rods [i.e. chittim] are based on objects used in real-life
> magical practices, but **I don’t know where they come from in the world
> of the novel**! They’re not from God, they just… fall from the sky when
> you learn something new.’